# sending form with php

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I am fairly new to writing php and I have a registration form where I want the information to be sent to my email but I think I am missing something in my mail.php as the information isn't coming through.

This is my html5 form:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Register</title>
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/register.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>


<div id="container">
<section id="register">

                 <form action="mail.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <h4>Your Jeep</h4>
                <div class="form-field">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Year</label>
                        <input value="" placeholder="Year" type="text"      name="year">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-field">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Color</label>
                        <input value="" placeholder="Color" type="text" name="color">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                 <div class="form-field">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Class</label>
                        <input value="" placeholder="Stock, Modified, Highly Modified"   type="text" name="class">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

               <!--------------------
                <div class="form-field">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Class</label>
                        <select class="form-field">
                        <option value="Select Class">Select Class</option>
                        <option value="Stock">Stock</option>
                        <option value="Modified">Modified</option>
                        <option value="Highly Modified">Highly Modified</option>
                        </select>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                 ------------------------->

                <div class="form-field">
                    <fieldset>
                        <label>Last 4 digets of VIN</label>
                        <input value="" placeholder="Last 4 digets of VIN" type="text" name="vin">
                    </fieldset>
                </div>




             </form>  


             <form>
                        <h4>You</h4>
                    <div class="form-field">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input value="" placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-field">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Address</label>
                            <input value="" placeholder="Address" type="text" name="address">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-field">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>City</label>
                            <input value="" placeholder="City" type="text" name="city">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-field">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>State</label>
                            <input value="" placeholder="State" type="text" name="state">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-field">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Zip</label>
                            <input value="" placeholder="Zip" type="text" name="Zip">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-field">
                        <fieldset>
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input value="" placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </form>

                  <form>

                       <div class="form-button">
                            <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">

                        </div> 



                   </form>




             </section>
  </div>           

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my mail.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>


<?php
$year= $_POST['year'];

$color= $_POST['color'];

$class= $_POST['class'];

$vin= $_POST['vin'];

$name= $_POST['name'];

$address= $_POST['address'];

$city= $_POST['city'];

$state= $_POST['state'];

$zip= $_POST['zip'];

$email= $_POST['email'];

$formcontent="From: $name \n From: $city";

$recipient = "mjadecole17@yahoo.com";

$subject = "JatB Registration";

$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

echo "Thank You!" . " -" . "<a href='index.html' style='text-decoration:none;color:#f15c25;'>        Return Home</a>";

?>



<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the form attributes, the `POST` method mainly:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

It specifies that the form will be send by `POST` and not by `GET`. As you are getting all your variables using `$.POST`, you need to send send the form by this method.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp).

Also, as @Frits pointed out, your `submit` button is in another form. You should only have one form in which you have all your fields as well as the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit button is in a different form!

You're submitting the empty form.

You have 3 forms total. Judging by the implementation of `mail.php` they should all be the same form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your submit button is in another form.

Second, you have not ended the comment tag correctly (but you browser handles it automatically).

Third, the mail() function is sending everything to the mailserver. So you need access to a mailserver to be able to send email with PHP.

Comment: I have made the changes suggested by @alvaro and the information is able to send. The email address the information would be going to is a hotmail... but if it's absolutely necessary I can  access a mailserver. Is this why there is an email window popping up to send the information when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: You need only one form which all inputs and buttons should be inside. Now you have two different forms. Then you need access to a mailserver to send email.

Comment: I put all the fields and the button in one form tag but now when I click submit a mail new message window comes up with information in the  subject box. Is this because of the absence of the mailserver?